# Bokeh: change the endpoints for /static

Tags: javascript, python, http, bokeh

#### Is there a way to change the endpoint that static JS files get served up from in Bokeh?

- I have a number of bokeh dashboards that are accessed from behind a load balancer
- Any request to https://myloadbalancer/{dashboard_name} is sent to the load balancer
- The loadbalancer then routes the requests to the correct dashboard server based on the value of /{dashboard_name}
- For any given dashboard, bokeh then attempts to access static javascript via https://myloadbalancer/static
- For this to work, I need to create a new bokeh server just to serve up static files and then configure the loadbalancer to route requests to https://myloadbalancer/static to the new server
- This approach is fine, until you start getting different javascript dependencies in the different dashboards
- Does anyone know of a way to change the /static path of a bokeh dashboard. So that for example it reads static files from https://myloadbalancer/{dashboard_name}/static?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run your `bokeh serve` command with the option `--prefix <base_path>`. This will put `<base_path>` behind every resource requested to the Bokeh (Torando) web server, this applies also for /static resources.

Here you can find the [official Bokeh documentation page](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/command/subcommands/serve.html#application-configuration).

Kind regards